# Error when trying to compare two coordinates to get a result

Tags: game-maker, gml

I'm making a score counter for my game. When two object's x coordinates' meet the score increases. I wrote a little script and execute it from my manager object. The error then occurs from my script and the error response is nonsensical to me.

The script:

```
if (obj_char.x == obj_ball.x)
{
    obj_manager.myScore += 1;
}
```

The error is as such:

```
############################################################################################
FATAL ERROR in
action number 1
of  Step Event0
for object obj_manager:

Push :: Execution Error - Variable Get 0.x(0, -2147483648)
 at gml_Script_scr_score (line 1) - if (obj_char.x == obj_ball.x)
############################################################################################
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
stack frame is
gml_Script_scr_score (line 1)
called from - gml_Object_obj_manager_StepNormalEvent_1 (line 9) - scr_score();
```

Comment: And both instances exists? Try to add a check before your code: `if instance_exists(obj_char) and instance_exists(obj_ball) { if (obj_char.x == obj_ball.x) ... }`

Comment: If this script isn't executed by an object but another script it may not even be able to find any of these objects. Maybe you have multiples of the same object?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to make sure both instances exist:

```
if(instance_exists(obj_char) && instance_exists(obj_ball) && instance_exists(obj_manager)){
  if(obj_ball.x == obj_char.x) obj_manager.myScore += 1;
};
```

Of course, if you have multiple instances of obj_char, you'll need to keep track of them. You can do that in whatever code you use to set up the room. For instance:

```
player = instance_create(64, 64, obj_char);
enemy = instance_create(240, 64, obj_char);
```

Now, you can place player or enemy in the same locations you would obj_char. Like this:

```
if(instance_exists(player) && instance_exists(obj_ball) && instance_exists(obj_manager)){
  if(obj_ball.x == player.x) obj_manager.myScore += 1;
};

if(instance_exists(enemy) && instance_exists(obj_ball) && instance_exists(obj_manager)){
  if(obj_ball.x == enemy.x) obj_manager.theirScore += 1;
};
```

Hope that helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

The obj_char or obj_ball dont exists when you run the code.
Try:

```
if instance_number(obj_char)>0 and instance_number(obj_ball)>0
{
    with obj_char
    {
        with obj_ball
        {
            if (other.x=x)
            {
                obj_manager.myScore+=1;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Now you can have 0 or many obj_char and 0 or many obj_ball and the score will increase whenever two of them meet.